# AngularStrap tooltip disables my custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am trying to get the bs-tooltip AngularStrap directive to work with my own custom directive called "checkStrength" which checks the strength of a password. When using either of these directives alone, they work fine, but they won't work together.

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/wNL441gbp2dIvVSl3G2e?p=preview) is a plunker with the bs-tooltip. The tooltip works fine but my custom "checkStrength" directive does not work.

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/yeikSFJlTKGL4CDM0eu4?p=preview) is a plunker without the bs-tooltip. In this case the "checkStrength" directive works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your input element you have to use the following:

```
ng-model="$parent.pw"
```

bs-tooltip creates an isolated scope on the element its bound to.

Working Example: [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/uULb0JcPyHWA4WAX5hWK?p=preview)