# Directive inside bs-tooltip is not evaluated

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-strap

I am trying to have a `<ul>` element with its own directive (checkStrength) inside of an AngularStrap bs-tooltip `title` property, like this:

```
$scope.tooltip = {  
  title: '<ul id="strength" check-strength="pw"></ul>',   
  checked: false  
};
```

The behavior I want is as follows: when a user clicks on the input textbox, a tooltip will appear showing the strength of the password as they enter it in the textbox.

This does not work, as shown in the two Plunkers below:

Custom "checkStrength" directive outside bs-tooltip works fine: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0S6UIrlB9tZ9cqDPiN6k?p=preview)

Custom "checkStrength" directive inside bs-tooltip does not work: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TwpYD97KpSO9R5vKSpcE?p=preview)

Comment: This is a duplicate question. I answered it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21126071/angularstrap-tooltip-disables-my-custom-directive/21126493#21126493

Comment: @Rob: to clarify, this is a separate question. I would like to insert the ul including the "checkStrength" directive inside of the tooltip. In the other question I had the ul tag outside of the tooltip (that issue is fixed now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it doesn't appear that this is supported out of the box. You are going to have to create your own binding directive

**Directive**

```
.directive('customBindHtml', function($compile) {  
  return {

    link: function(scope, element, attr) {
          scope.$watch(attr.customBindHtml, function (value) {
              element.html(value);
              $compile(element.contents())(scope);
          });
    }
  };

});
```

This go into Angular Straps code and make the follow modification on line 10 of tooltip.js in the plunker

**Template**

```
<div class="tooltip-inner" custom-bind-html="title"></div>
```

Then set the html property in the config to false.

**Config**

```
.config(function($tooltipProvider) {
  angular.extend($tooltipProvider.defaults, {
    html: false
  });
})
```

**Example:** [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/WpN4OpjzpI7BdntGW77X?p=preview)